# Complete unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

i have a question
Write a program to check the validity of password input by users.
Following are the criteria for checking the password:

1. At least 1 letter between [a-z]
2. At least 1 number between [0-9]
3. At least 1 letter between [A-Z]
4. At least 1 character from [$#@]
5. Minimum length of transaction password: 6
6. Maximum length of transaction password: 12

Your program should accept a sequence of comma separated passwords and will
check them according to the above criteria. Passwords that match the criteria are
to be printed, each separated by a comma
Example
If the following passwords are given as input to the program:

```
ABd1234@1,a F1#,2w3E*,2We3345
```

Then, the output of the program should be:

```
ABd1234@1
```

the solution is below

```
def check_password(word):
    special_str = "$#@"
    accepted = []

    passwords = word.split(',')

    for password in passwords:

        lower = 0
        upper = 0
        digits = 0
        special = 0

        for char in password:

            if char.islower():
                lower += 1
            elif char.isupper():
                upper += 1
            elif char.isdigit():
                digits += 1
            elif special_str.find(char) != -1:
                special += 1

        if lower >= 1 and upper >= 1 and digits >= 1 and special >= 1 and len(password) in range(6,13):
            accepted.append(password)

    return accepted
```

i was told to also write a unit test for it 
Now am new to using unit tests, so after going through some examples i tried writing a unit test as below

```
import unittest
import question1

class Test_PasswordChecker(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_valid(self):
        self.assertEquals(question1.check_password("ABd1234@1,a F1#,2w3E*,2We3345"),'ABd1234@1')

if __name__ == '__name__':
    unittest.main()
```

The source code works well, though am having problems on whether i have made the correct unit test for it.
Need some help on how to make the best unit test

Comment: Tip: when you paste code on Stackoverflow you should *first* paste the code, *After that* select it and press the `{}` button. Otherwise you end up with the wrong formatting as in your original question.

Comment: "Need some help" is too broad for Stack Overflow.  It seems that you're asking for a personal tutorial on testing; this is off topic.  Can you narrow this to an appropriately specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code has an issue: you are *printing* the result instead of `return`ing it.

As a general principle you should always strive to decouple input-ouput to "processing". If you have functions that both compute stuff *and* print/request input you end up reducing their reusability and testability.

In this case the issue with your unittest is that `check_password` always returns `None` since you did not return anythign and hence it will always fail.

So first thing replace:

```
print(accepted)
```

with

```
return accepted
```

Now: you need more than one test for this function. You should try to write a test for all possible cases.

For example:

- check what happens when no password satisfies the requirements?
- What happens if all satisfy the requirements?
- What happens if you give the empty input to the function?
- For each requirement try to see what happens if you try to call the function with a password that satisfies all requirement except that one.(e.g. a password that has a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter, a symbol, a digit but whose length is 4 or 20).

Basically you should try to divide the possible input into a number of categories and check at least one input for each category.